# Do we follow "is" with a gerund or infinite?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

Do we follow "is" with a gerund or infinite? For instance, should I say

"Our goal is to eliminate distractions?"

or

"Our goal is eliminating distractions?"

Thank you

Comment: You can say either.

Comment: But they don't always amount to the same thing. **He is going alone** is a statement. **He is to go alone** is an instruction. Similarly, **She is dying** and **she is to die**.